# Why didn't @Transactional work with @Autowired EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I had a problem with persisting objects to the database using Spring 4.3, JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.
Figured out something was wrong with transactions.
Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

   /**
     * most bean methods skipped, left only the relevant ones
    **/


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.company");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

---

Here is my service. The code has run, no exceptions were thrown. But the object was not persisted to the database. I have intuitively understood that either something was wrong with a transaction creation (as the logger didn't show any transactions) or data was not committed to the database. `EntityManagerFactory` **was not null**.

```
@Service
public class Manager {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Transactional
public void persist(Entity entity){
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.persist(entity);
}

}
```

---

After I replaced `@Autowired EntityManagerFactory` with `@javax.persistence.PersistenceContext EntityManager`, everything worked fine.

```
@Service
public class Manager {

@javax.persistence.PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;


@Transactional
public void persist(Entity entity){
    entityManager.persist(entity);
}

}
```

Why doesn't it work with `@Autowired EntityManagerFactory`?

Comment: Because you are creating a new `EntityManager` with that, which is not the transactional entity manager, hence no commit on the `EntityManager` used to call `persist` on. With auto wiring the `EntityManager` you will get the transactional `EntityManager`.

Comment: @M.Deinum: could you add your comment as an answer, so I'll be able to accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Spring for transaction management and as such you want to get the current transactional `EntityManager`. If you are injecting the `EntityManagerFactory` and use it to get an `EntityManager` you have a good change you end up with a new one, this new one isn't bound to the started transaction.

Instead inject the `EntityManager` using `@PersistenceContext`

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em.
```

If you really want to inject the `EntityMangerFactory` you have to use `@PersistenceUnit` instead of `@Autowired`. The `@PersistenceUnit` is handled different then a plain `@Autowired`.

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Comment: @m-deinum Just to be sure. EntityManager should be injected in Spring service or repository only using PersistenceContext annotation, not Autowired. Correct?

Comment: Although both would work in a Spring based application, stick with the general JPA way and use `@PersistenceContext`.

Comment: @m-denium, and does `@Autowired` create a separate `EntityManager` for each transaction (like `@PersistenceContext` does) and not a single `EntityManager` bean for the whole application?

Comment: Yes it works the same, you get a proxy that will create a thread bound `EntityManager` when needed.